# Reporting interactions in a linear model in r

Tags: r, linear-regression, interaction

I am trying to report all the interactions in a linear model that reads:

```
mod1.lme <- lm(volume ~ Group * Treatment + Group + Treatment, data = df)
```

Group is a factor variable with 3 levels: A, B and C.

The result that I currently get is for (I made up the data):

[image]

These two estimates are in reference to Treatment:A, but I would like to see each effect independently. So the output that I would like to get is:

```
Treatment:A
Treatment:B
Treatment:C
```

If I eliminate the intercept adding -1 at the end I get:
[image]

What is the best way to code this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the output that you are, is that one of the factor levels of `Treatment` becomes a reference level. When interpreting the model the coefficients become "the difference in effect from the reference level". This is necessary as long as the model includes an intercept, so the only way to get the interpretation with all coefficients shown is to remove the intercept as shown below.

```
mod1.lme <- lm(volume ~ Group * Treatment - 1, data = df)
```

## Edit:

To change the name of the interaction effect, one would have to edit the name manually

```
sum.lm <- summary(mod1.lme)
rownames(sum.lm$coef) <- c("groupA","groupB","groupC", "groupA:Treatment", "groupB:Treatment", "groupC:Treatment")
```

or alternatively use another package for summaries such as [`sjPlot`](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/tab_model_estimates.html#defining-own-labels-1)

```
library(sjPlot)
tab_model(mod1.lme, pred.labels = c("groupA","groupB","groupC", "groupA:Treatment", "groupB:Treatment", "groupC:Treatment"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I know eliminating the intercept you avoid the reference, but only in the Groups as whole effects. My interest is in the interactions. A:treatment, B:treatmente, C:treatment. Does it make sense? Can that be done?

Comment: Hi @Lili, what you are saying sounds exactly like removing the intercept. How is what you're looking for different from the effects shown by `summary(mod1.lme)` with an intercept removed?

Comment: I have edited the text for more accuracy :) thanks

Comment: Ah makes sense. You want to change "Treatment" to "Treatment:groupA", to make it obvious that it is still affected by the study group. Here you are going to hit a wall. It is most definitely possible, but formatting coefficients names is not an option in `help(summary.lm)` or it's print method (same page). The simplest way would be to store the summary in a varible and change the name afterwards, or use a package which provides more options (such as [`sjPlot`](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/tab_model_estimates.html#defining-own-labels-1)).

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand correctly. I don't want to change the name. I just want the interactions on their own without being referenced. At the moment what I see is how treatment affects volume in group B compared to group A, and the same for C. But I want to know the effect of treatment in volume in each group. Does it make sense? - Thanks!! :)

Comment: Hi @Lili, you seeing the same thing as you are asking for. By removing the intercept, `Treatment` describes the effect on volume in `group==A`, as there is simply no other option. The remaining levels are no longer references to `group==A`, but to a virtual `intercept==0`. The interpretation becomes **"the effect of group B is [insert group b coefficient] and the effect of treatment in group b is [insert treatment:groupB coefficient]"**. Note that I did not say "the effect of group B compared to group A" or "the effect of treatment in group B compared to group A".